# CUDA: Building graph from nodes

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, gpgpu

I am using CUDA to build an undirected graph from a list of nodes. Each node has a  coordinate in 3-dimensions and my program creates an edge between two nodes if the nodes are separated by less than some cutoff distance d.

Now I am storing the edges in the form of an adjacency list. The problem is, I have 1024 threads computing pairwise distances asynchronously. Once an edge is 'discovered' between nodes A and B, I need to increment the number of edges for node A and place node B at the 'next-available' position in the adjacency list.

Here, CUDA is giving me nightmares. I want the adjacency-list-update process to be critical, but CUDA does not seem to provide anything beyond atomicAdd(). As a result, I am getting unpredictable behavior and a different adjacency list every time I run the code.

Is there a way to asynchronously create the adjacency  list? Perhaps through a more clever data structure?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the atomicAdd() with a [prefix scan](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html) to yield reproducible results. Alternatively, you could sort the results in a separate step.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of nodes is big enough I would map one thread to one node, so each node calculates distances to all other nodes and stores them to its private adjacency list. In that case, if the order of calculations is defined(what is done by ordering of node list) no indeterminism occurs. Some code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < listOfNodes.length(); i++)
    if(dist(listOfNodes[threadId], listOfNodes[i]) < cutoffDist) {
        int n = adjacencyLists_sizes[threadId]++;
        adjacencyLists[threadId][n-1] = listOfNodes[i];
    }
```

If the number of nodes isn't big enough(using CUDA I suppose it is) you can divide calculations between one node and all the other nodes among threads of one block, each thread calculates equal part of distances. Using `__syncthreads()` ensures 
determinism.

Comment: Thanks. I already tried that. It works, but I find it annoying that most of the threads are sitting idle. I am also using a domain decomposition to limit the number of distance computations for each node, to yield around 100 nodes per block. I think I'll accept the problem of asynchronous writes and tinker with my nodes per block so that I get maximum occupancy of each thread.  BTW I have between 1E6 and 1E9 nodes, so this strategy is not that bad.

Comment: Actually it is no problem if most of the threads are sitting idle. The thing that matter in this case is number of calculated distances per second what is determined by occupancy of your GPU streaming multiprocessors(SM) and by efficiency of the algorithm. If running thread blocks fully occupy GPU and rest of them are waiting for releasing of SMs you get maximal throughput.